# Nested job with mlflow in azure sdk2

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, mlflow

I have searched about nested or child job in azure sdk2 and find something in mlflow.start_run with a parameter named nested which set True to be child job:
[nested job notebok I found](https://ml.azure.com/fileexplorerAzNB?wsid=/subscriptions/fcfad08d-c789-4a11-937f-c032b15ee290/resourcegroups/rg-mlk-ai/workspaces/mlk-ai&tid=abb7ff0d-7e3b-47a5-9269-65e243fc21b2&notebookPivot=1&activeFilePath=Samples/SDK%20v2/sdk/python/using-mlflow/train-and-log/xgboost_nested_runs.ipynb)

But it doesn't help me, I think it don't have any option to give it parent run.
Could anyone help me with this?
Or any other solutions to create a job in child job part of another job in azure ml studio?

Something like this job in this picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on MLFlow [Documentation,](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.start_run)

Once you start the parent run then you can create a nested child run inside it.

```py
import mlflow
# Create nested runs
experiment_id = mlflow.create_experiment("experiment1")
with mlflow.start_run(
    run_name="PARENT_RUN",
    experiment_id=experiment_id,
    tags={"version": "v1", "priority": "P1"},
    description="parent",
) as parent_run:
    mlflow.log_param("parent", "yes")
    with mlflow.start_run(
        run_name="CHILD_RUN",
        experiment_id=experiment_id,
        description="child",
        nested=True,
    ) as child_run:
        mlflow.log_param("child", "yes")
```

So, if you have a existing job, then you can create a child run with same `experiment_id` and `nested=True`.
[image]

For other example, please check [Hyper-parameter optimization using Hyperopt and nested runs in MLflow](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/using-mlflow/train-and-log/xgboost_nested_runs.ipynb) that demonstrate more details on how to transfer metrics, parameters, and artifacts from child runs to parent runs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to make my problem clearer.

I have a train script which preprocess data and train a model. I want to test this model with another data in another notebook named test script. I want to have this job in test notebook, as a child of train job.

I mean my parent run is a train run and my child run is it's test

Could I explain my situation?